# How to recognize events on child nodes for recognizers with Hammer.js

Tags: javascript, hammer.js

My scenario:
-I have a sidebar with thumbnail images on it

What I'm trying to achieve:
- Swiping away the sidebar to close it

Where I'm stuck:
- Swiping on the sidebar works fine, but if the swipe is started over the image thumbnails, it doesn't register as a pan event on the sidebar, so it only works if blank space is the origin of the swipe

I'm not using jquery, just straight JS + Hammer.js

```
function setupSidebar(elem){
  let sidebar = new Hammer.Manager(elem);
  sidebar.add(new Hammer.Pan({ direction: Hammer.DIRECTION_LEFT, threshold: 0}));
  sidebar.on('panstart',function(){ isPanning = false; });
  sidebar.on('pan',dragX);
}
```

The above is how I'm binding the event to the sidebar itself.  It's called from a loop that simply loops through anything with a specific className.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue.  I was using e.target rather than this, to reference the object in the actual code run.  That is what was preventing the child events from triggering the drag.